# Root vs system signature

Tags: android

What are the differences in priviledges in Android of root access vs system signature?

I'm having trouble uninstalling a system app with system signature, and I read that it can be done via root.
Can someone explain conceptually what the differences are?

In the end I want to know how to programmatically uninstall a system app.

Comment: In the end I want to know programmatically how uninstall of system app can be done

Comment: It's been a while since this was opened so I'll try to answer based on what I know now. From my understanding, ROOT is the master user which has all privileges, and apps with a system signature has privileges that is a subset of that. I believe System App under /system/app is another ID but I can't be sure.